# Inherited control will not display in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-controls

Trying to create a simple custom control in C# Winforms that inherits from Panel, but as soon as I change it to inherit from "Panel" instead of "UserControl" I get this error:

[image]

Here's the code for the entire class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SETPaint
{
    public partial class Canvas : Panel
    {
        public Canvas()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Canvas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the line 'this.AutoScaleDimensions = ...' in your Designer.cs file (line 35 according to the exception). There's probably another similar to 'this.AutoScaleMode = .Font' too.

This problem arises because you've used the Designer when the Control derived from UserControl, and it set some default properties in the InitializeComponent() method. Those properties are part of the UserControl base type, but not the Panel base type.

Since the IDE Designer can't load the Designer.cs file to fix this problem, you need to do it manually.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SETPaint
{
    public class Canvas : Panel
    {

    }
}
```

And on the toolbox there should be an item called Canvas after you build the solution

Comment: Sorry, I do have all of those using statements but did not include them in the original post, I updated it to be more complete.

Comment: RJ Lohan's solution worked, I just needed to delete those lines that didn't work. Not totally happy about that being the solution, but apparently that's what is required when you inherit from a specific control instead of User Control.

Comment: @cArn - Your example code implies there will be no InitializeComponent method in the Canvas control, which is not necessarily the case, and only hides the problem rather than fixing it.

Comment: @AdamWathan - if you'd never opened the control in the Designer whilst it was derived from UserControl, I believe these erroneous lines would never have been inserted by the IDE.